# How do I change my username on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, account-management

I have changed by username 5 times and now I'm unable to change it. I want to change my username now, as I got married.

I want to know how to delete the other user names.

Comment: Why are you applying all of these tags to your question, there's no reason for them.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook doesn't allow you to change your name by yourself more than 5 times. They do provide a form where you [can request for a change in name](https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/245617802141709), but bear in mind you will need to provide a scan of Government issued ID for it to go through.